# Make non-wrapping div expand when content overflows the page

Tags: html, css, width, overflow, expand

When a div has `white-space: pre` and has too much content, it will overflow the page, adding a scrollbar. How do I get the div to be as wide as it expands to?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TkcTZ/1/

If you scroll to the right, you'll see that the background only extends to the right of the viewport, not past the edge behind the overflowing text. If you inspect the div with web tools, you will see that it is because the div is only as wide as the background.

How do I make divs expand widthwise when their content overflows? I would like a CSS/HTML only solution (no javascript).

Comment: Try this: word-wrap: break-word;

Comment: @AliGajani I don't want word wrapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have fixed it by setting `display: table` and `width: 100%` on the containing div, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/TkcTZ/3/

Answer (score 2):

`display: inline-block;` to the rescue!

```
div {
    white-space: pre;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I can't make it inline-block, because each one needs to be on its own line, and it needs to take up 100% width as well, like a normal div. Doing inline-block with `width: 100%` has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following updated fiddle should work for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/TkcTZ/2/

I have update the code with `overflow:auto;`
This makes sure that div covers all its content with its background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use overflow: auto to make the div scrollable so that the background color takes the 100% of the div width.

```
div {
    white-space: pre;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/nkHGZ/

Comment: I can't make the div scrollable, it is contained within another div that controls the scrolling, as in the jsfiddle.