# Make HTML div expand when content is added with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I know there are other questions that deal with this, but they aren't working for me.

I have a `<div class="column">` and inside this `div` there is another `div` called `<div class="truck">`. Now there is going to be a button that will add other "truck" columns to the `column` div. I want the column div to expand when I add a new truck. As it stands, the extra truck is added, but to view the other truck, I have to scroll to the left. I want the column to expand with each new truck that is added. The below code doesn't have the button that I was referring to, as I have Javascript adding the next truck to each column at the moment.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="calendar">
        <div class="column" id="day1">
            <div class = "truck" id="day1_truck1">
                <p>This is truck one</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column" id="day2">
            <div class = "truck" id="day2_truck1">
                <p>This is truck one</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column" id="day3">
            <div class = "truck" id="day3_truck1">
                <p>This is truck one</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column" id="day4">
            <div class = "truck" id="day4_truck1">
                <p>This is truck one</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column" id="day5">
            <div class = "truck" id="day5_truck1">
                <p>This is truck one</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column" id="day6">
            <div class = "truck" id="day6_truck1">
                <p>This is truck one</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column" id="day7">
            <div class = "truck" id="day7_truck1">
                <p>This is truck one</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#main
{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black; 
    width:97%;
    height:900px;
    margin:50px, auto, 10px, auto; 
    padding: 1%;
    overflow: auto; 
    white-space: nowrap;

}
#calendar
{
    
}
.column
{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black; 
    min-width:12%;
    max-width:100%;
    width:auto;
    height:800px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:1%; 
    overflow: auto;

}
.header
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    text-align: center; 
    font-style: bold; 
}

.truck
{
    width:80%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black; 
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

You can see that the extra truck div is cut off. Here, you can scroll to see it, but I want both divs to be displayed.

What am I doing wrong? I have tried to set the overflow to `hidden` and other suggestions from these links:

> [make div's height expand with its content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709442/make-divs-height-expand-with-its-content)
>
> [Make non-wrapping div expand when content overflows the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199479/make-non-wrapping-div-expand-when-content-overflows-the-page)

I've also tried a couple other things from a couple other sites.

Any help would be appreciated. I know this can be done with Javascript, but I'm pretty sure that it can be done without it. If Javascript is my only option, that's fine, I just figured I'd try to avoid it as doing it in HTML/CSS would be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to make the new truck column go beside the other truck in the same column or underneath it?

If you want the div to go beside [( DEMO )](http://jsfiddle.net/qC5bk/94/) the previous one change your .truck CSS code to this:

```
        .truck
    {
        width:auto;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: black; 
        display:inline-block;
    }
```

To make it post underneath, change the .truck CSS to this:

```
    .truck
    {
        width:auto;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: black; 
        display:block;
    }
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. And, yes, I want them next to each other.

Comment: I can't comment yet :( I don't have enough rep! And I'm still not sure if I understand what your problem is or what you are trying to do.